# What is the difference between a packed and an unpacked Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What are the practical differences?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Packed** are extensions that have been compiled into a downloadable .crx file. These are the files you download and install from such places like the Chrome Web Store.

**Unpacked** are extensions that are available from your computer. Typically all the source files within a folder when you are developing an extension.

Answer (score 3):

Not much in terms of functionality. Unpacked is used for development. Packed is when you need to distribute it. You cannot run an unpacked extension unless you enable developer mode, so not really practical if you're trying to distribute your app.